# HubClass is Undefined issue with Class Library

Tags: signalr, owin

Hub class is undefined issue when putting the HubClass into Class Library.

I am using a Class Library that contains the HubClass.

when I am accessing the hub class in client side, I am getting the HubClass is undefined issue.

var hub=$.connection.signalHub (here signalHub is undefined)

/signalr/hubs is loading fine without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Its one of 2 things, either you forgot to set the name of your hub in the attribute on the hub class, or you have a typo. Likely capitalization is incorrect.

Did you mean var hub=$.connection.signalrHub or var hub=$.connection.signalHub

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply Kelso.....

I have used the Hub name in client side correctly (i.e signalHub since the Server side HubClass name is SignalHub).

I got the issue. The issue is due to,

The HubClass's Access specifies was private by mistake... :-D

When I changed that to Public , it is working as expected.